# How to properly read .nfo file with PHP

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to open and show a nfo file with a php script.

Everything is working but the result isn't like in the NFO file. I got special chars like that :
�������������������������

When I open the source code of the result, I can see the NFO file like he is in real!

Did I need to use some special tricks for HTML or something like that ?

Answer (score 2):

You can convert the character encoding of your NFO text (to output to eg. utf8):

```
$nfoContent = file_get_contents('foo.nfo');
$nfoContent = mb_convert_encoding($nfoContent, 'UTF-8', 'ASCII');
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your reply!

I found it, in PHP you just need to do :

header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=ansi');

Comment: Be aware that with this you'll restrict your site's character set to 8-bit ansi. This means you won't be able to print symbols like: λ

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');

$file = 'CORE.NFO';
$nfo = file_get_contents($file);

echo '<pre>';
echo iconv('CP850', 'UTF-8', $nfo).PHP_EOL;
echo '</pre>';
```

http://pastebin.com/uqxg4yYC

CP850 west europe

CP866 russia

https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/NFO

Comment: CP850 some characters might be distorted. try CP437

Comment: could you explain me why my answer isnt usefull?